# Center link lines on elements Ngx-Graph

Tags: ngx-graph

I have been using ngx-graph for the first time. I am trying to restrict the link position on the elements they are linking. For example I have the situation below. I will have multiple links coming from the parents and going to children nodes.

All I want is the link start and end points to be in the same spot off the parent and children. In the image I have provided I would like vertical center on the right for the parent and vertical center left for the child. I see that the "Custom Curve" example on the documentation illustrates this to a point, I am just having a hard time trying to replicate that same setup for a large div in my node or link template. They keep wanted to reset to the top or bottom of the element.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I needed to empty the cache and hard reload Chrome. It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

normally for this type of issue, the position can be changed by changing the x and y value in the svg